# How to mitigate named UDP spoofing?

Tags: bind

How can `named` be configured to require TCP for updates and log that TCP was used?

eg:

```
Jul  6 11:01:28 server named[865]: client @0x7f89200aa3d0 1.2.3.4#58841: update 'domain.tld/IN' denied
```

should end in T or U

like for queries https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00434

... I'm looking for mitigations for a naive standard.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse-path_forwarding#Unicast_RPF